# C - Creating an array of character arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to make an array of character Arrays. The program will read in sentences and store the sentences in a character array, and then that character array will be stored in another array. After reading numerous websites and Stack Over Flow pages I think it can be done like this. The program breaks when trying to store my character array into another array, so i'm not sure how to correct my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int size;          //number of sentences
    char strings[100];// character array to hold the sentences
    char temp;


    printf("Number of Strings: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &size);   // read in the number of sentences to type
    char **c = malloc(size); //array of character arrays

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < size)       //loop for number of sentences
    {
        printf("Enter string %i ",(i+1));
        scanf_s("%c", &temp); // temp statement to clear buffer
        fgets(strings, 100, stdin);
        // **** this next line breaks the program
        c[i][j] = strings;   // store sentence into array of character arrays
        j++;
        i++;
}
printf("The first character in element 0 is: %d\n", c[0][0]);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot store a character array in another character array. You can store a character array in an array (I adapted your question's text accordingly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al you need to do is allocate the memory for the string just read and copy the string:

```
c[i][j] = strings;   // replace this with:

c[i]= malloc(strlen(strings)+1);
strcpy(c[i],strings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly `char **c` is not array of characters arrays. But this will properly allocate a 2d array dynamically if you follow

```
char (*c)[SIZE];
```

And then doing this

```
c = malloc(sizeof(char[LEN][SIZE]));
```

Then you do what you are trying to do.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < LEN; i++){
    if(fgets(c[i],SIZE,stdin)){
    ...
    }
}
```

Or you can do it like this

```
char **c = malloc(LEN);
..
for(size_t i = 0; i < LEN; i++){
   c[i] = malloc(SIZE);
   ...
}
```

But again `c` is nothing but jagged array of characters.

Check the return value of `malloc` and free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Listen dude,
Do you want to store the words in the character array and then store this in another array.
It is what you want ?
If yes then you can do the following.

Use stdlib by using `# include <stdlib.h>` .
This lets you use string functions directly.
Now read every word as a string and make array of strings.
So now if you number of strings is n, define an array for that as `string my_array[n]`  and scan each word using `scanf("%s",&my_array [i])`.
In this way you will get an array of strings.